# Example of FindUnrelatedTypesInGenericContainer Bug

Tags: java, generics, findbugs

I tried hard to find any documentation which kind of bug pattern the (per default not enabled) findbug detector `FindUnrelatedTypesInGenericContainer` should detect. From its name and source I would assume it detects the bug in the following snippet, but it does not:

```
Set<String>[] sets = new Set[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  sets[i] = new ConcurrentHashSet<String>();
  sets[i].add("Foo");
}
PoJo p = new PoJo("Foo");
sets[5].remove(p); // <- bug
```

So could anybody

1. clarify for which kind of bug the detector is made and
2. tell whether there's a detector which detects the bug from above?

Answer (score 1):

The following would cause detecting the bug in question (which looks similar to the one described in [this link](https://sonar43.spring.io/rules/show/findbugs:GC_UNRELATED_TYPES?layout=false)):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(1);
System.out.println(set.remove("x"));
```

The only difference between this and your snippet is that yours features an array of a generic type. Perhaps FindBugs is unable to detect the bug in this case.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I filed a [bug with findbugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1387/).